# Quick Dial Shortcut with Skype

Tags: home-screen-shortcuts, skype

Is it possible to make a desktop shortcut to dial a number with Skype?

Comment: Not that I have found. It doesn't appear possible at this point. Sounds like a good enhancement for a future release.

Comment: Anyone found a solution for this since the last posting? Would be great to have this option like exists for normal contacts - that is you could link to IM a Contact on Skype or Call.

Comment: I dont think the Skype app has an api to do this I agree it would be great. This may be possible in the future with ICS I was testing my voip sip account to make internet calls, now whenever I make a call I am able to use the option to call with either wifi internet sip or regular mobile.

Comment: No you can't make quick dial shortcut in skype, But you can send this idea as a request to skype for apply in future versions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a new widget available from Google Play Store that solves this issue:

[Direct dial with Skype](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.sbice.android.oneclickskype) by sbice

> One Click Skype!
>
> Calling friends through Skype is no longer time consuming and complicated!
>   With "Direct dial with Skype", it's simply just ONE CLICK AWAY!!!
>
> It's a widget installed on your desktop & help you speed dialing your friends with ONE CLICK!

Comment: It's not working in one click.
I have a problem with the NFC toggle. If this is off (default it's off) it isn't working.