# How to put a Call contact using Skype shortcut widget on the home screen?

Tags: contacts, app-widgets, skype, home-screen-shortcuts

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Quick Dial Shortcut with skype](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/2171/quick-dial-shortcut-with-skype)

Is it possible to make a desktop shortcut to dial a number with skype?